# Remove notification inside service android

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have a notification on one of my services. Below is the code:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                                .setContentTitle("title")
                                .setContentText("content")
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_small_notif)
                                .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                                .setSound(alarmSound)
                                .setColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"))
                                .build();

                        startForeground(100,
                                notification);
```

I still confused how to stop this programmatically when I want to. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `stopForeground(true);`

it works with foregroud tasks.

Comment: one more thing, I have two of this notification, and both merged into one notification. How can I separate them?

Comment: I dont know any solution . As I know this is a restriction of Android OS.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(mnotinotifId);
    manager.cancelAll();
```